# How to select full row in ALV grid?

Tags: abap, alv

I need to return to a specific line in ALV in the code with `cl_gui_alv_grid`. I use `set_current_cell_via_id`, it works, but only a cell is selected. How to programatically select the full row?

[image: result of cl_gui_alv_grid set_current_cell_via_id]

Thanks

Full code:

```
DATA gr_alvgrid TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid.
DATA gt_t005t TYPE TABLE OF t005t.
PARAMETERS dummy.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  IF gr_alvgrid IS NOT BOUND.
    CREATE OBJECT gr_alvgrid
      EXPORTING
        i_parent = cl_gui_container=>screen0.
    SELECT * FROM t005t INTO TABLE gt_t005t WHERE spras = 'E'.
    gr_alvgrid->set_table_for_first_display(
        EXPORTING i_structure_name = 'T005T'
        is_layout = VALUE #( sel_mode = 'D' )
        CHANGING it_outtab = gt_t005t ).
  ENDIF.
  DATA sroid TYPE lvc_s_roid.
  DATA irow TYPE i VALUE 2.
  SROID-ROW_ID = iRow.
  CALL METHOD gr_alvgrid->set_current_cell_via_id
    EXPORTING
      IS_ROW_NO = SROID.
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Let me propose you. Could you verify it please?

Comment: You need to use method SET_SELECTED_ROWS or you want the checkbox to be selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the method `SET_SELECTED_ROWS` to achieve this result:

[image: result of method SET_SELECTED_ROWS of cl_gui_alv_grid]

Full code:

```
DATA gr_alvgrid TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid.
DATA gt_t005t TYPE TABLE OF t005t.
PARAMETERS dummy.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  IF gr_alvgrid IS NOT BOUND.
    CREATE OBJECT gr_alvgrid
      EXPORTING
        i_parent = cl_gui_container=>screen0.
    SELECT * FROM t005t INTO TABLE gt_t005t WHERE spras = 'E'.
    gr_alvgrid->set_table_for_first_display(
        EXPORTING i_structure_name = 'T005T'
        is_layout = VALUE #( sel_mode = 'D' )
        CHANGING it_outtab = gt_t005t ).
  ENDIF.
  gr_alvgrid->set_selected_rows( it_row_no = VALUE lvc_t_roid( ( row_id = 2 ) ) ).
```